# Beep sound notification on Socket connection establishment

Tags: android

How can I make the Device sound a beep when socket connection has been established. In other words, how to set a notification tone when an event occurs in Android sdk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the one opening the socket, use `MediaPlayer` or `SoundPool` or `ToneGenerator` or `AudioTrack` or something to play back a beep.

If you are trying to arrange for beeps when other applications open sockets, that is not possible without firmware modifications.